# pandas-groupby: apply custom function which needs 2 columns as input to get one column as output

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with dates and a value per day. I want to see the gradient of the value, if it is growing, declining, .... The best way is to apply a linear regression with day as x and value as y:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                   'day':[1,2,4,2,3,4],
                   'value':[1.5,2.4,3.6,1.5,1.3,1.1]})
```

df:

```
  customer  day  value
0        a    1    1.5
1        a    2    2.4
2        a    4    3.6
3        b    2    1.5
4        b    3    1.3
5        b    4    1.1
```

By hand I can do a linear regression:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
def gradient(x,y):
    return LinearRegression().fit(x,y).coef_[0]

xa = df[df.customer =='a'].day.values.reshape(-1, 1)
ya = df[df.customer =='a'].value.values.reshape(-1, 1)
xb = df[df.customer =='b'].day.values.reshape(-1, 1)
yb = df[df.customer =='b'].value.values.reshape(-1, 1)
print(gradient(xa,ya),gradient(xb,yb))

result: [0.68571429] [-0.2]
```

But I would like to use a **groupby** as in

```
df.groupby('customer').agg({'value':['mean','sum','gradient']})
```

with an output like:

```
               value     
          mean  sum  gradient
customer           
a          2.5  7.5   0.685
b          1.3  3.9  -0.2
```

the issue is that the gradient needs 2 columns as input.

Comment: Numpy has a diff function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# calculate gradient
v =  (df
      .groupby('customer')
      .apply(lambda x: gradient(x['day'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1), 
                                x['value'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)))
v.name = 'gradient'

# calculate mean, sum
d1 = df.groupby('customer').agg({'value': ['mean', 'sum']})

# join the results
d1 = d1.join(v)

# fix columns
d1.columns = d1.columns.str.join('')
print(d1)

               valuemean     valuesum  gradient
customer                                       
a                   2.5           7.5  0.685714
b                   1.3           3.9 -0.200000
```